# Issue appending newly changed variable and outputting with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with the following code.

I am trying to change the content of a variable if a `button` is clicked and then output the corresponding content as part of a larger output. The output varies depending on if the inner `button` within the `form` is clicked.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this code or improvements?

In the output I should see a longer version as the extra block would be appended on to the newly created block and grab new id values generated. Any help would be great.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var currentID = 1;
        $(':button#add').on('click',function() {
            currentID++;
            var clone = $('#content').clone();
            clone.children('.content_title').attr('id', 'title_content-' + currentID);
            clone.children('.content_more').attr('id', 'more_content-' + currentID);
            clone.attr("id", "content_1");
            clone.insertAfter('#content');

            if(currentID >= 2) {
                document.getElementById("add").style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <h1>Create Code</h1>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><span class="number"></span>Header</legend>
                    <label for="name">Title:</label>
                    <input type = "text" id = "title" />                                                   
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id = "content">
                    <legend><span class="number"></span>Content</legend>
                    <label for="name">Title:</label>
                    <input class = "content_title" type = "text" id = "title_content" />
                    <label for="mail">Content:</label>
                    <input class = "content_more" type = "text" id = "more_content" />
                </fieldset>
                <input id = "add" type = "button" value = "Add" />                                                                                                                                                         </form>
                <button onClick="tryTest()">Code</button>
        </div>
        <div style = "float:left; width:48%; padding-left:10px;">
            <p id="new_block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function tryTest() {
            var quote = '"';
            var start = "<pre>&lt;div class=" + quote + "newest" + quote + "&gt;</pre>";
            var title = "title=" + quote + document.getElementById("title").value + quote;
            var end = "<pre>&lt;/div&gt;</pre>";

            var start_1 = "{{widget type=" + quote + "new_version" + quote;
            var title_1 = "title=" + quote + document.getElementById("title_content").value + quote;
            var content_1 = "content=" + quote + document.getElementById("more_content").value + quote;
            var end_1 = "template=" + quote + "other" + quote + "}}";

            var title_2 = "title=" + quote + document.getElementById("title_content-2").value + quote;
            var content_2 = "content=" + quote + document.getElementById("more_content-2").value + quote;

            var widget = start_1 + "<br />" + title_1 + "<br />" + content_1 + "<br />" + end_1; 

            var widget_1 = start_1 + "<br />" + title_1 + "<br />" + content_1 + "<br />" + end_1 + start_1 + "<br />" + title_2 + "<br />" + content_2 + "<br />" + end_1; 

            if(add.clicked == false) {
                document.getElementById("new_block").innerHTML = start + "<br />" + title + "<br />" + end + "<br /><br />" widget + "<br /><br />";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("new_block").innerHTML = start + "<br />" + title + "<br />" + end + "<br /><br />" widget_1 + "<br /><br />"";
            }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a strange mix of jQuery and vanilla JavaScript syntaxes...
But it would work if there was no parse error.

Those error were quite easy to find in a code editor like [CodePen](https://codepen.io/), by the way.

```
  if(add.clicked == false) {
    document.getElementById("new_block").innerHTML = start + "<br />" + title + "<br />" + end + "<br /><br />" + widget + "<br /><br />";
    // Added a missing + sign --->                --->                --->                --->               here -------^
  } else {
    document.getElementById("new_block").innerHTML = start + "<br />" + title + "<br />" + end + "<br /><br />" + widget_1 + "<br /><br />";
    // Added a missing + sign --->                --->                --->                --->                 here -------^
  }

}  // Added this curly bracket to close the tryTest() function.
```

Just above this code block, is a condition to choose which string to append to `new_block`.

The `if(add.clicked == false) {` condition always evaluates to false, because `add` is not defined. So the property `.clicked` of undefined, obviously also is undefined...
Then `"undefined" == false` is false... And makes the `else` block to always execute.

This condition fixed will avoid the `Cannot read property 'value' of null` error on "Code" click if the "Add" has not been clicked.

There is a couple ways to determine if the "Add" button has been clicked.

1. Check if the element `title_content-2` exist
2. Use a boolean "flag" turned to true on "add" click
3. Adding a class to the "Add" button on click

I will let you think about the solution you would prefer and try it.

Here is your code freed of the mentionned syntax errors in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/eEKjYZ?editors=1010).